# jQuery mousemove fade in/out element cancel fade on element mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this code which fades out the navigation menu to 50% opacity when the mouse is dormant:

```
var hidden, fadenav, dimNav = function () {
    hidden = true;
    $('#main-nav').animate({'opacity': 0.5}, 200);
};

$('document').ready(function () {
    dimNav();
    $('body').on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (hidden) {
            $('#main-nav').animate({'opacity': 1}, 200);
            hidden = false;
        }
        if (fadenav !== null) {
            clearTimeout(fadenav);
        }
        fadenav = setTimeout(dimNav, 500);
    });
});
```

What I want to do is make it so that it doesn't fade when the user has their mouse over the `#main-nav` element.

I have tried this to no avail:

```
$('#main-nav').on('mouseover mouseout', function (e) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseover') {
        clearTimeout(fadenav);
    } else {
        fadenav = setTimeout(dimNav, 500);
    }
});
```

does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I think hoverIntent should help you http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: how would hoverIntent help me here? This has nothing to do with the user accidentally moving their mouse off the element, or detecting if the user intended to hover over an element. I simply need to cancel a timeout on mouse over of an element but it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this certainly is not less code but it may be a bit more straight forward:

```
​$('#main-nav').on('mousemove',function(e){
    if(hidden){
        $('#main-nav').animate({'opacity': 1}, 200);
        hidden = false;
    }  
    clearTimeout(fadenav);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

add that instead of:

```
$('#main-nav').on('mouseover mouseout', function (e) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseover') {
        clearTimeout(fadenav);
    } else {
        fadenav = setTimeout(dimNav, 500);
    }
});
```

you don't have to play with classes at all.

Here is my working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/TbwSA/1

EDIT: I realized that you don't even need the mouseout event.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution myself and thought it might be worth other people knowing:

first, you need to do something similar to this:

```
$('#main-nav').on('mouseover', function (e) {
    if (!$('#main-nav').hasClass('hovered')) {
        $('#main-nav').addClass('hovered');
    }
}).on('mouseout', function () {
    if ($('#main-nav').hasClass('hovered')) {
        $('#main-nav').removeClass('hovered');
    }
});
```

and then change the `dimNav()` function to this:

```
dimNav = function() {
    if (!$('#main-nav').hasClass('hovered')) {
        hidden = true;
        $('#main-nav').css('opacity', '0.5');
    }
};
```

If anyone can think of a better method than this, please contribute!